# Cant find dynamic xpath using chropath : It might be child of svg/pseudo element/comment/iframe from different src.Currently ChroPath doesn't support

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to use xpath to find input in a textbox a card number but the id is dynamic and class contains multiple hyphens , its not able to find the xpath i have tried for the given html

```
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none add-cc-number
    <input type="tel" id="pp-XQAs3V-15" autocomplete="off" name="addCreditCardNumber" class="a-input-text a-form-normal a-width-medium" data-testid="pmts-account-Number">
    </div>
</div>
```

When i use chropath it says It might be child of svg/pseudo element/comment/iframe from different src. Currently ChroPath doesn't support for them.

Xpath tried:
//input[contains(name(),'ppw-accountHolderName')]
tried with ancestor sibling too.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

name() is an XPath function to get te name of een element.

If the input has this name addCreditCardNumber use this:

```
//input[@name='addCreditCardNumber']
```